# C++ run error when using endl

Tags: c++

I've recently started to learn C++ and I'm trying to compile and run a very simple program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cout << "Hello Again!";

    return 0;
}
```

The program itself compiles as it should without any errors, however, when the program runs, it seems to stop after `cout << "Hello World!" << endl;`. I find this very strange, as my friend is sitting right beside me, doing the exact same thing and it works for him. The same thing happens when I try to use the `sizeof();`; it does not return any value, however, when my friend does this, it works.

When I ran it in NetBeans, it first generated the error

> RUN FAILED (exit value 255, total time: 2s)

And another time I ran it, it generated the same error, but with a different exit value. Although it is now back to 255.

When running debugger in NetBeans it produces

> SIGILL (Illegal instruction)

a few times before it stops working.

I have installed the MinGW compiler at the default directory (C:\MinGW), and this is the compiler that NetBeans and any other program is using. I have also added the path to the System Environment Variables at the end of the "Path" variable:

> ;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

Trying to run and compile the same code in Atom results in

> Hello World!Press any key to continue . . .

I have tried reinstalling the compiler, and restarted my computer. None of which seems to work. I've also tried `\n`, which works.
My question is, is there anything wrong with my compiler or computer, or am I missing something obvious? And is it possible to fix this?

(Sorry if this is a duplicate, I've searched for a few hours, not able to find anything useful)

Comment: Nothing obvious. Something's seriously wrong. Doubt we can solve it from here. However, the lack of output is only down you not flushing your second line of output, and the crash (whatever is causing it) terminates your program before IOStreams does the automatic end-of-program flush. Put `endl` back and you'll see both lines. Then you can concentrate on what is causing the crash.

Comment: can you show an example with your `sizeof` error?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have included.  If that is the code you are compiling, you have a problem with your installation.  Have you got a program installed that your friend hasn't? (or visa-versa)

Comment: @RyanHaining
`#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 *
 */
int main() {

    cout << "Size of char: " << sizeof(char);

    return 0;
}`

Will in NetBeans return the same error, and in Atom it will return "Size of char: Press any key to continue . . ."

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet adding `endl` behind the second line of output will result in the same error in NetBeans, and same output in Atom.

Comment: @MartinBonner We have too many programs to compare with each other.

Comment: Then you'd best get started!

Comment: I can't imagine why `sizeof` would cause a crash, especially at runtime. What happens if you `cout << 0;`?

Comment: @RyanHaining

`cout << 0;` will crash the same way; no output in Atom and error in NetBeans,
However if I try to `cout << "0";`, which is a string, it works as expected.

Comment: okay now we're onto something. it look like you can't write anything out that isn't a `const char*` so let's play with that some more. I'm gonna give you a couple of examples to try and see what crashes and what doesn't.

Comment: first: `std::string hello = "hello world"; std::cout << hello;`

Comment: second: [link here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee5bc536537e67d6)

Comment: @RyanHaining the first code you gave me returned `RUN FAILED (exit value -1 073 741 511, total time: 29ms)` in NetBeans, and nothing in Atom.
The second code you gave me returned `hello
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 47ms)` in NetBeans and `helloPress any key to continue . . .` in Atom.

Comment: it looks to me like your `<iostream>` is messed up. Does this extend to printf as well? can you write `std::printf("%d\n", 0);`? (after a `#include <cstdio>`)

Comment: @RyanHaining `std::printf("%d\n", 0);` returns `0

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 217ms)` in NetBeans and `0
Press any key to continue . . .` in Atom. I included the cstdio

Comment: I'm starting to think it's a linker problem and that `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const char*);` is in the header. What else is going on with your stdlib? Can you create a `std::string` without writing it out?

Comment: @RyanHaining `std::string hello = "Hello World!";` returns `RUN FAILED (exit value -1 073 741 511, total time: 34ms)`. I'm not trying to write it out anywhere, I'm just declaring the variable.

Comment: ok yeah your standard library isn't actually being dynamically link at run time (I'm pretty damn sure). You'll have to investigate the settings in your environments, I don't know enough about netbeans to tell you how to do it, but look around for "netbeans linker options" or similar. The problem is that although all the headers are there, the libraries aren't being linked in(think all the .h files but none of the .cpp). However since it uses dynamic linking it's not showing up until run time.

Comment: @RyanHaining, I've been looking around for Linker settings in NetBeans, and compared my settings to my friend's settings. They are completely identical, and I can't find anything in the settings, what so ever, that is different.

I also tried adding the Libraries from MinGW, but with no luck. (I have no idea if this is the right way to do things).

[Linker options](https://i.imgur.com/bgRMhCo.png), 
[Libraries options](https://i.imgur.com/L5QQBlv.png).

(Although the library option is empty, so is my friend's).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the culprit!
In my System Environment Variables, `C:\MingGW\bin` and `C:\MingGW\MSYS\1.0\bin` was at the bottom of the list. This meant that it was below `C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub` (Which I think, if I'm not mistaken is another compiler).

Although all paths in NetBeans were correct, it seems like the system didn't like it when another compiler was listed above MinGW.

I solved the problem by moving the paths for MinGW up, above the GNU.

Comment: Hm. Two different compilers using two different stdlibs? If the headers of one don't match the library of another, that'd do it.